# Github Linking with Reference Project(s) in Github with Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2017

I'm developing two diffrent project at same time with Github. (one for main, one for reference dll) I want to reference project is should be in main repository, and reference project should be in own repository. Like this (ss from github) ;

[image: Sample Struct]

And I want to make cross-development with two project and single solution at same time (reference should be a project in solution file) in Visual Studio 2017 (Using github extension).

- SampleSolutionStruct (in SampleRepository)

  - Project1
  - Project2
  - Project3
  - Reference1 (in SampleReferenceRepository)

I think this Github repository have a liked sub-repository. When I click reference1 folder, my URL address is redirected to the other repository's URL.

Comment: Where is your question? ;)

Comment: Question is simple : How can I do that ? :)